# How to allow Node.js server to take all request on Ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu

I have a Node.js program running on Mac and Windows, both allowing visitors over the internet. My set up is super simple:

```
var http = require('http');
var s = http.createServer();
s.listen(80, process.argv[2] || '127.0.0.1');
```

And when I run the server I will use `node server.js 0.0.0.0` to trigger `process.argv[2]` so it doesn't just listen on the request from the local server.

Yet when I move the same server application to Ubuntu, it stops working. For example, if the Ubuntu server has an IP address of 172.18.x.x, it will only response to requests from machines in the same network, having IP address of 172.18.x.x. If a device has an IP address of 172.19.x.x, it doesn't response. It also doesn't response to forwarded internet calls if the forwarded request didn't come from a routing machine that has an IP address of 172.18.x.x!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This likely has nothing to do with Node.js. It is probably your Ubuntu system that is blocking the connection. Specifically, some firewall or security package installed as a dependency by one of your apps, or otherwise.